# Since packets holds next hop MAC address, how does a switch knows to which port to send a packet to a destination?

Tags: switching

Lets say a switch has 4 ports : P1, P2, P3, P4
Host A is connected to P1
Host B is connected to P4

If Host A wants to send a packet to Host B, the packet will have as destination address the MAC address of P1 or the MAC address of P4 or the MAC address of Host B ?

Comment: Here's a clue:  switches used to be called "transparent bridges."

Comment: @RonTrunk Please explain me. Everywhere I go people tell me about CAM table and ARP. I already know this stuff. I'm just asking when a packet leave a host, what is dest MAC address ? If it's the switches address then how does the switch know to which dest to send it ? If it's the dest MAC addr, then how does a send tell the packet to go to its switch port (or is it that send blidly sends everything on the wire and swicth does the rest ?)

Comment: How does the host know that if it’s connected to a switch or another host?

Comment: @RonTrunk I don't know. I'd say maybe the NIC tries to see is it can send bits on a wire, then it assumes the host on the other end of the wire is the switch. Am I correct ?

Comment: Suppose two hosts are connected together with just a cable. What is the destination MAC and how does the first host know it?